# Whether spring cloud config cache/store config data from backend

Tags: spring-cloud-config, hashicorp-vault

In my project, I am planning to use multiple backend to store different data in my spring cloud conifg server setup: use git backend to store un-sensitive data, and use vault to store sensitive data like password/token. This is simiar to what https://content.pivotal.io/blog/spring-cloud-services-supports-vault-multiple-backends-use-the-right-config-repo-for-the-job suggests.

My question is since the returned decrypted value from vault is passed back to "client application" through config server, will config server cache/store/log the response from vault in any way. If this is true, config server will be a big target for hacker and we may have to protect the config server with extra configuration.

Comment: did you find an answer to this question? If so, please share, I am really interested in the answer...!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the true answer to your concern would be to secure each and every layer of your stack to prevent intrusion at any single point.

The [Spring documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html) makes no explicit reference to caching data - so you should be safe in that regard. It would also not make a lot of sense for Config Server to cache the configuration from external data stores as it is not the source-of-truth for that data. We want it to always fetch the data from source to ensure we get the latest version of the data. I'm supposing that there *might* be a case of caching **if** Config Server stored the configuration locally and was **able to watch** the files for changes and refresh its cache accordingly. But having said that, I'm still not sold on the benefit of caching at this layer.

From personal use of Spring Cloud Config Server I've yet to see it logging out the entire configuration; in-fact it logs very little to start off with. I'm sure you can suppress logging even further by setting the appropriate levels.

What you should also look at doing is securing the connections between Vault & Config Server and Config Server and each application using SSL. That will prevent you from transmitting data in clear text and will provide you with an additional layer of security.

Comment: I don't know about vault, but when config server is using a git server, it does cache every repo that it retrieves, even if it is set to refresh for each request. There is no way to turn off that behavior. It doesn't log it, but it does cache it to the file system. Vault might be different. I would not make any assumptions about caching based on it not being documented. But if you encrypt your sensitive values in your git repos, the local cache will have the encrypted values, so that seems secure enough. (Not sure what the advantage is of vault over git server.)

Answer (score 0):

Problem with spring cloud config server cache the token
Do this changes in spring cloud config server side

```java
public class NoSessionManager implements SessionManager {
    private final ClientAuthentication clientAuthentication;
    public NoSessionManager(ClientAuthentication clientAuthentication) {
        this.clientAuthentication = clientAuthentication;
    }
    @Override
    public VaultToken getSessionToken() {
        return clientAuthentication.login();
    }
}
```

add this class in spring config

```java
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.vault.authentication.SessionManager;
import org.springframework.vault.config.AbstractVaultConfiguration;
 
@Configuration
public class VaultSessionManagerConfig {
 
    @Bean
    public BeanPostProcessor sessionManagerBeanPostProcessor(AbstractVaultConfiguration vaultConfiguration) {

        return new BeanPostProcessor() {
            @Override
            public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
                if (SessionManager.class.isInstance(bean)) {
                    return new NoSessionManager(vaultConfiguration.clientAuthentication());
                }
                return bean;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

this is working on my side